# Pandas - filtering duplicated records by multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Can anyone help with this.

1. If Col B is duplicated, and col D has all record values D, exclude
2. If Col B is duplicated 2 times, and col D has 1 value D, or col B is duplicated 3 times and two of those has value D on Col D, so on... exclude
3. keep others

[image]

Comment: It may be useful to look at drop_duplicates() and groupby() functions

Comment: There are two Column Bs. Is the second one Column C?

Comment: Sorry, third one is meant to be B

Answer (score 0):

Taking a similar dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': ['p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 's', 's', 't', 't', 't'],
    'D': ['A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D']
})
df
    B   D
0   p   A
1   q   D
2   q   D
3   r   A
4   s   B
5   s   A
6   t   A
7   t   D
8   t   D
```

You can group by B and use `filter` to get the required columns. `func` counts number of Ds and then checks the required conditions. If condition for removing is satisfied, return `False` such that that group is removed

```
def func(x):
    cnt_d = (x['D'] == 'D').sum()
    len_x = len(x)
    if (len_x > 1 # to check if it is a duplicate
        and (len_x == cnt_d or (len_x == 2 and cnt_d == 1) or (len_x == 3 and cnt_d == 2))):
        return False
    return True

df.groupby('B').filter(func)

    B   D
0   p   A
3   r   A
4   s   B
5   s   A
```

Comment: Thanks @ggaurav, Is there a way I can add a loop in this statement within the function :len_x == cnt_d or (len_x == 2 and cnt_d == 1) or (len_x == 3 and cnt_d == 2) or (
                    len_x == 4 and cnt_d == 3)   meaning lenx ==j and cnt_d ==j-1 and j goes up to the length of dataframe.

Comment: Yes, you can add a loop. But you should avoid a loop. Each call to `func` will have a dataframe corresponding to a group. you can print x and maybe you will get the idea

Comment: Thank you. How can I modify this function to check condition such as I have 6 values duplicated on column B and 5 of them have value D on col D, or 7 duplicated in Col B and 6 of them are value D, and so forth. I need these excluded from the output.

Comment: you can approach on similar line - `(len_x == 2 and cnt_d == 1)` --> `(len_x == 7 and cnt_d == 6)` or if you can have a general solution, you can replace all these conditions with `cnt_d == len_x - 1`